# Try to run "npm start" after creating office add-in project

Tags: api, office-js

I created a office365 add-in project in apline container following the online instructions.
However, when I try to run "npm start". it gives following error:

**Starting the dev server... (webpack-dev-server --mode development)
(node:191) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Platform not supported: linux**

So does that mean, I can only run the add-in project on Windows?

Comment: Please confirm are you able to run Angular or React in your linux ?

Comment: I haven't tried creating Angular/React project. Is it related? I will try and come back to you later.

Comment: Hi, I just tried creating Angular project. But still canot run "NPM start". It gives the same error as the previously mentioned.